# Replacing multiple different characters in a string with their morsecode values

Tags: java, replace

I am writing a program which translates a string (an input from the user) to morse code. At first I was going to use multitudes of if and else if statements, but that found teh replace/replaceAll function in java. thsi proved to be quite useful. However, given my mediocre programming skills, I could not figure out how to replace multiple different characters in the same string. Here is part of the code:

```
  Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the text you want translated to 
Morsecode:");
        String input = reader.nextLine();
        String res = "";
        String[] letters = new String[] {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f",  "g", 
"h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", 
"w", "x", "y", "z"};
        String[] codes = new String[] {".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", 
"..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---",  ".-
-.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", 
"-...", "--.."};
        int i=0;
        for (i=0;i<26;i++)
        {

            res = input.replaceAll(letters[i], codes[i]);
        }
        System.out.print(res);
```

If I input the string to be "aabb", the program outputs the following result: ".-.-bbaa-...-...", this result is not far from the desired result (I think), but I cannot understand where the "bbaa" comes from? 
Thanks

EDIT: I have edited the original question based on the suggestions given by some answers. However, the current codde only prints out the string that has been input to the program

Comment: You could use a single `String` : `String morse_code_input = input.replace("a", ".-").replace("b", "-...");`  .

Comment: Try printing out the results of the `replace` calls.

Comment: @JornVernee isn't the last system out statement doing that?

Comment: @Berger ok i will give it a go

Comment: Well yeah but, you said you don't understand why it's printing `bbaa`, so looking at the intermediate result might help you.

Comment: @BarryBBenson : the problem is that you have a string which is the original string with the `a` replaced, and another which is the original string with the `b` replaced, so the first one still has the `b` and the second one still has the `a `.

Comment: @Berger I have tried what you said and it works, I have made 26 of those replace statements, but i was wondering if it was possible to have 2 letters in the same replace statement, as both A and a have the same morse code

Comment: See the answer by @dasblinkenlight , it perfectly suits your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track with `replaceAll`. Here is how you can complete this program:

- Make two `String[]` arrays - one with letters, and one with their corresponding Morse codes
- Make a loop that walks the array, and calls `res = res.replaceAll(letters[i], codes[i]);`
- replacements should be followed by space; otherwise you wouldn't be able to tell if `.--...` represents `ab` (`.-` `-...`) or `ws` (`.--` `...`)

The two arrays would look like this:

```
String[] letters = new String[] {"a", "b", ...};
String[] codes = new String[] {".-", "-...", ...};
```

**Note:** Once you are done with the initial version of the program, try figuring out a way to eliminate the `letters` array by generating a string with `i`-th letter of the alphabet from its number `i`.

Comment: @zlakad There's no need to use `enum` because programmers have no reason to access the individual `enum` constants by name. That's why this should be a container, not a group of individual values.

Comment: I will alter my code with consideration to your example above, thanks

Comment: I have triesd your method and it looks like the code just prints out the string input into the program

Comment: I'll edit my question so you can see what i have tried

Comment: @BarryBBenson Put `String res = input` before the loop, and change to `res = res.replaceAll ...` inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

All changes have to be applied on the same string:

```
String s = reader.nextLine();
s = s.replace("a", ".-");
s = s.replace("b", "-...");
System.out.print(s);
```

Also you might consider adding a blank after every code for learning purposes: ".- ".

Answer (score 0):

Make a `HashMap` with letters as keys and morse code codes as values. Then Loop through your input String and for each character in the String append the appropriate morse code code to output `StringBuilder`.

```
String input = "Lorem ipsum";

    Map<String, String> charTable = new HashMap<>();
    charTable.put("A", ".-");
    // other characters

    StringBuilder sbOut = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        String character = String.valueOf(input.charAt(i));

        sbOut.append(charTable.get(character));
    }

System.out.println(sbOut);
```

This has the benefit of being more readable and easier to debug than the option with two arrays and I feel (I haven't tested it) that it is more efficient also.

Answer (score 0):

While a `replaceAll` **can** be used to accomplish what you need, it's far from being efficient, as 1) you will be creating String instances on each replacement, and 2) you will have to iterate over the source string multiple times (once for each character you replace). A more efficient way would be to maintain a StringBuilder instance, where you will append your transformed result, and to iterate over the source string using `source.toCharArray()`. Also, to save yourself from typing a multitide of `if` statements to replace each character, maintain a `Map<Character, String>` map of English characters to their Morse equivalents. Then the whole replacement would look rather simple:

```
Map<Character, String> translation = new HashMap<>();
map.put('a', "._");
// repeat for each character representation
// this map can be initialized once, e.g. as a static
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("");
for (Character c : input.toCharArray()) {
    result.append(translation.get(c));
}
return result.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree, that `String.replaceAll()` for each single letter works fine. BUT, do not forget, that every time when you do replace, JVM create new string. Therefore for a long string, you have lots of objects for GC.

I offer to use `String.toCharArray()` along with `StringBuilder` to convert given string into morse code:

```
public class Morse {
    private static final Map<Character, String> CODE;

    static {
        Map<Character, String> map = new HashMap<>();

        map.put('a', ".-");
        map.put('b', "-...");

        CODE = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
    }

    public static String encode(String str) {
        if (str == null)
            return null;

        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            String code = CODE.get(str.charAt(i));
            buf.append(code != null ? code : " ");
        }

        return buf.toString();
    }
}
```